# .NET Core 3 Preview Data is null error on multiple .Includes

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a simple query that looks like this:

```
return await _context.Blog
.Include(x => x.Posts)
.Include(x => x.People)
.ToListAsync();`
```

When this runs, it throws a "Data is null" error.  The stack tracke starts like this:

```
at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid.get_Value()
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetGuid(Int32 i)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Query.Pipeline.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.IncludeCompilingExpressionVisitor.IncludeCollection[ 
   TEntity,TIncludedEntity](QueryContext queryContext, DbDataReader dbDataReader, 
    TEntity entity, Func`3 outerKeySelector, Func`3 innerKeySelector, Func`4 
   innerShaper, INavigation navigation, INavigation inverseNavigation, 
   Action 2 
    fixup, Boolean trackingQuery, ResultCoordinator resultCoordinator)
```

If I remove one of the .Includes, the query runs fine.  I can remove either one and the query works, so it doesn't seem to be related to one specific entity.  My dbcontext has relationships defined like this:

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.Blog)
.WithMany(b => b.Postenter code heres)
.HasForeignKey(r => r.BlogsID)
.HasConstraintName("FK_Post_Blog");
```

Is there some type of bug with the preview version?

Comment: Hi... you have points: can you fix the formatting?

Comment: Preview (beta) software, you know. Such things are expected. Tried with the latest previews and although not getting the exception you are describing, the program entered infinite loop. As you said, it happens when you have more than one collection `Include`. I guess you need to wait for 3.0 release.